# Raven.Server.exe Failed to grant rights for listening to http

Tags: ravendb, netsh, http.sys, ravendb-http

I have installed RavenDB 2.5.0 as Windows Service.
When I try to run Raven.Server.exe as Administrator or not I receive this:

```
Trying to revoke rights for http.sys
runas netsh http delete urlacl url=https://+:8080/
Trying to grant rights for http.sys
runas netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user="Endri-PC\Endri"
Failed to grant rights for listening to http, exit codes: (1 and 1)
A critical error occurred while starting the server. Please see the exception de
tails bellow for more details:
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not write to location: C:\RavenDB\Databa
se\System. Make sure you have read/write permissions for this path. ---> Microso
ft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentFileAccessDeniedException: Cannot access file, the fi
le is locked or in use
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Initialize(IUuidGenerator uuidGen
erator, OrderedPartCollection`1 documentCodecs)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Raven.Storage.Esent.TransactionalStorage.Initialize(IUuidGenerator uuidGen
erator, OrderedPartCollection`1 documentCodecs)
   at Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase..ctor(InMemoryRavenConfiguration configura
tion, TransportState transportState)
   at Raven.Server.RavenDbServer..ctor(InMemoryRavenConfiguration settings)
   at Raven.Server.Program.RunServerInDebugMode(RavenConfiguration ravenConfigur
ation, Boolean launchBrowser)
   at Raven.Server.Program.RunInDebugMode(Nullable`1 anonymousUserAccessMode, Ra
venConfiguration ravenConfiguration, Boolean launchBrowser, Boolean noLog)
   at Raven.Server.Program.<>c__DisplayClass34.<InteractiveRun>b__1b()
   at Raven.Server.Program.InteractiveRun(String[] args)
   at Raven.Server.Program.Main(String[] args)
Press any key to continue...
```

Any idea what to do ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just had this same problem while I was following the "Basic Concepts" section of the RavenDB documentation, with the following output:

```
C:\RavenDB>Raven.Server.exe
Trying to grant rights for http.sys
runas netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user="User-PC\User"
Failed to grant rights for listening to http, exit codes: (0 and 1)
A critical error occurred while starting the server. Please see the exception details bellow for more details:
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not write to location: C:\RavenDB\Data.
Make sure you have read/write permissions for this path. ---> Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Interop.EsentFileAccessDeniedException: Cannot access file, the file is locked or in use
<stack trace follows>
```

The issue was that the RavenDB installer had automatically started the RavenDB Server as a Windows Service, preventing the command-line Raven.Server.exe from being able to access the right directory.  I just opened the Services control panel (Start menu -> services.msc) and stopped the RavenDB service.  After that, starting Raven.Server.exe from the command line worked as demonstrated in the documentation.

Note that this is running on a Windows 7 x64 Professional machine in Development mode with RavenDB 2.5.2851.

Comment: Just to note that since the service is running you need not run the console app at all. Just open the browser with localhost:8080 and you'll see the RavenDB databases, all working as expected. (Empty as default)

Answer (score 0):

You have neither the permission to access port 8080 nor the database folder. If you want to run RavenDB on your account, give yourself permissions for the folder `C:\RavenDB\Database\System` and run this command in an elevated console:

> netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/

Comment: I have already given full control to my account, the Administrator account still has it too, but still the same error ...

Comment: The exception says that the used account is not Administrator but **Endri-PC\Endri**

Comment: again, i have given full rights to my account Endri-PC\Endri, also to Administrator account, also i've tried to run the above command on CMD with Run As Administrator, but still the same.
these are elementary things in a computer to know about ...

Comment: also, it is not uncommon to receive an exception that's unrelated to the real problem